# How to get Body Fat Percentage data from HealthKit?

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm trying to create a widget for myself so I can see my measurements on the screen.

I successfully get Body Mass and Body Mass Index data from HealthKit, but my code doesn't work for fetching the Body Fat Percentage data.

Couldn't find anything about Body Fat Percentage on my search, so I wanted to ask if I need to use a different way to fetch its data?

Function for fetching the data:

```swift
class func getMostRecentSample(for sampleType: HKSampleType,
                               completion: @escaping (HKQuantitySample?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
    
    let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast,
                                                          end: Date(),
                                                          options: .strictEndDate)
    
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate,
                                          ascending: false)
    
    let limit = 1

    // This step won't execute as usual while working for Body Fat Percentage data; 
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType,
                                    predicate: mostRecentPredicate,
                                    limit: limit,
                                    sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in
    
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        guard let samples = samples,
              let mostRecentSample = samples.first as? HKQuantitySample else {
                
              completion(nil, error)
              return
        }
        
        completion(mostRecentSample, nil)
      }
    }

    HKHealthStore().execute(sampleQuery) // then jumps to here.
}
```

Function for getting the string from the fetched data:

```swift
class func getSamples(for sampleType: HKSampleType,
                      unit: HKUnit,
                      completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
    
    
    
    getMostRecentSample(for: sampleType) {(sample, error) in
        guard let sample = sample else {
            return
        }
        
        let BMI = String(sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit))
        // let weight = String(sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit))
        // let fatPercentage = String(sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit))
        
        completion(BMI, nil)
    }
}
```

Sending the data to Timeline then preview it:

```swift
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<WeightEntry>) -> Void) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let refreshDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
        guard   let bodyMass = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass),
                let bodyMassIndex = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMassIndex),
                let bodyFatPercentage = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyFatPercentage) else {
                return
        }

        ProfileDataStore.getSamples(for: bodyMassIndex,unit: HKUnit.count()) { (sample, error) in
            guard let sample = sample else {
                return
            }
            
            let entry = WeightEntry(date: currentDate, value: sample)
            
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [ entry ], policy: .after(refreshDate))
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your app have read authorization for body fat percentage and is there data in health app?
Are you saying the sample query isn't calling the completion? What happens if you pass a nil predicate in the query?

Answer (score 0):

What unit are you passing as body fat? Should be percentage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."